# Why won't div take width of its closest parent?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
 <div class="container col-lg-12 col-sm-12">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 clear-L-R">
             <div class="fix">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/400/nature" class="img-responsive clear-L-R center-block" alt="">

                <div class=" caption caption-text">
                    <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
                    <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 clear-L-R">
            <div class="fix">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/400/nature" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">

                <div class="caption caption-text">
                    <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
                    <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<style>


body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}    




.caption{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
    left:0;   /** new  **/
    right:0;  /** new  **/
}
.caption:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
.caption-text h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.caption-text{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}    

</style>
```

http://velnikolic.com/ToddNew/

The caption should only take the width of the .fix div, but its taking its value from the col-lg-6 div can't figure out why. Scroll down to gallery for example. Tried to follow an example on here, but it's still doing that after triple checking the code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is taking width of `.fix` div

Comment: the caption is taking the width of the wrapper above it not the fix div. width 100% did nothing on the image. its the caption thats too big it should be the size of the image see the image. all the "grey" is the padding from the div above it.

Comment: which one i tried width: 100%

Comment: takes mate! mind explaining a bit, im bad with positioning and all that

Answer (score 1):

position style is missing in `.fix`

```
.fix {
position:relative;
}
```

**Explanation**

`position: absolute` Div will be respective to nearest parent with `position: relative`

Comment: it works but, when the images resize it breaks again. see new image

Comment: add `width:100%` in `.center-block` class